# Spinner Hanging and TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Hangs with spinner even though loading says false in devtools. Individual Post won’t display.

[image: Spinner Hanging]

In Post.js, I comment out:

```
// if(post === null || loading || Object.keys(post).length === 0) {
```

Instead only keep:

```
if(post === null || loading) {
```

Then I get the error: `CommentFeed.js > TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined.`

Repo: https://github.com/annacho/devconnector

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone is going to pull your gihub code and try to recreate your issue. Can you try and and boil it down to a code sample that you can post into your question? Have you checked the javascript console for errors? Spinners don't hang, they just don't get the next message that tells them to stop spinning.

Comment: That is because when you take out  `|| Object.keys(post).length === 0` you are no longer validating that the post props has any content... in CommentFeed.js this line is the one with the error `return comments.map(comment => (. and once again, this happens because the post prop has no content